# spring hibernate version issue

Tags: hibernate, spring, annotations, version

I am using following libs:

hibernate
            hibernate-core
            3.6.3.Final
        
        
            hibernate
            hibernate-jpa
            2.0-api-1.0.0.Final
            provided

Along with spring 3.0.5 RELEASE libs

But I am getting the follwoing error while AppContext loading:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager in EnvironmentClassLoader.

Looks like I might be missing the hibernate-annotation jar, if thats correct which version should I use. I tried several, but leading to version conflicts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class is in `hibernate-commons-annotations-3.0.5.Final.jar`.

P.S. I recommend you to improve your answer rate.

Comment: Thanks! Mindas. I will try this..and try to improve my answer rate as well :)

Answer (score 0):

For Any Hibernate Jar Version related issue , check with hibernate-entitymanager jar version . Because

> entitymanager jar internally contains compiled jar of hibernate core ,
>   annotations , commons-annotations etc.

Rectifying the version of entitymanager will solve your dependency problem on other jars.